# Need help on inproving this 7.4V LiPo battery bypass circuit design

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I came across this 4 year old post where this circuit below was the answer to use and charge a 3.7V Lipo Battery, as a Li-PO bypass circuit.

[POST](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39805/can-you-charge-and-use-a-lipo-battery-at-the-same-time)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f94dSV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need the exact same circuit, but for a 8.4V (2S) battery instead (and 5V in the output, instead of 3.3V - but that's simple).

After asking in the arduino site (where the post above was done some years ago) I was told that this bypass circuit above  works only for the 3.7V battery because VIN on the Gate of the P Mosfet must be higher than the Battery's voltage.

So I came up with this solution so far below. Adding another DC-DC Step up converter from 5V to 9V on the VIN to make Vin higher than VBatt:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFCRfi.png)</sup>

But I'd like to know if there's some other simple way of doing this bypass circuit without having to add this extra Dc-Dc 9V step up regulator, with few components if possible..

EDIT: My 8.4V Charger boosts 5V from VIN to 8.4V output to charge the battery.

Thanks

Comment: How is the charger supposed to charge a 8.4V battery from 5V supply? Can it boost voltage?

Comment: @Justme Yes. This one boosts from USB type C 5V to 8.4V, at 2A input (1.1V Output for the battery)